# to get the path of a war file deployed in the jboss SOA server

Tags: jboss, path, soa, war, web-deployment-project

i want the path of the war file that is deployed in the jboss SOA server .
as the file can be deployed in any of the folder

all, default, minimal, production, standard, web

so i dont want to hardcode my path , whenever i need to find a file in any of these folder  . 
please help me in the following matter .

i have one more question as when a war file is deployed can we put a xml file with it external to the war file.

Comment: Why do you need the full path? In most situations better solutions are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be able to as the .war file will be unpacked before the web application is started and the web application will therefore not have, nor need, knowledge of the .war file it was previously archived in.

Comment: but the foder is still same..like if i deploy in production than it will be there in the production only....thats why how can i know that the deployed and running application belongs to which folder